# VS code throw compile error on Azure Static web app with c# as api

Tags: visual-studio-code, .net-core, apple-m1

I created a new azure static web app. I use react.js for frontend and c# for azure function. I am using VS code on a MacBook with M1 chip. VS code won't compile the azure function and throw the following error.

```
Metadata generation failed. Exit code: '130' Error: 'Failed to load /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/3.1.30/libhostpolicy.dylib, error: dlopen(/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/3.1.30/libhostpolicy.dylib, 0x0001): tried: '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/3.1.30/libhostpolicy.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have (x86_64), need (arm64e)))An error occurred while loading required library libhostpolicy.dylib from [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/3.1.30]'
```

The error seems related to the I don't have the correct .net SDK installed. So I checked all installed SDK and runtime. It all seems fine. Can someone give me some clues how to fix this?

```
dotnet --list-sdks
6.0.300 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
6.0.301 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
6.0.302 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
6.0.400 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
6.0.401 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
6.0.402 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
dotnet --list-runtimes
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.5 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.6 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.7 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.8 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.9 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.10 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.25 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.26 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.27 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.28 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.29 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.30 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.5 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.6 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.7 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.8 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.9 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.10 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

Comment: The error seems to indicate an architecture mismatch - x86 vs arm64?  However, it may be more complicated than that.  Give this Github thread a read, it has your exact `libhostpolicy.dylib` error =https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/59168#issuecomment-964101605